# ways to ease remote Unix server adminstration tasks

Tags: ssh, putty

We have a dedicated CentOS server running Apache, PHP, Mysql.

I'm normally on a remote Windows 7 machine, and I use Putty to SSH into the CentOS server.

Time and time again i find myself having to copy from a growing text file where i have lists of commands, and paste in Putty, or else keep pressing that up arrow in Putty, to get to a command I entered previously.

How can i ease this task?

I guess the ideal would be a Windows SSH program, where I can have a toolbar with buttons to press, that would just paste the predefined command into the ssh terminal and press Enter for me. Does something like this exist?

Comment: (1) Press ctrl-R and type a few characters to search through the command history for a command that you want to repeat.  Press ctrl-R again to get the previous match if the first isn't what you want.  For many more options, read about command `history` in `man bash`. (2) If you have the same series of commands that you want to repeat one after the other, then you want to create a shell script.

Comment: I didn't know about ctrl-R, but i just tried a few and now the terminal is not responding to anything...frozen  at  `(reverse-i-search)`':`

Comment: I guess that was a one time bug, After restarting the session,  ctrl-R works fine. Good tip! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways that you can ease your task. Tho I am unaware of something for windows to easily send commands to a linux box.

The simplest would be to have the commands in a bash script that you can run localy on your Centos System.

Also with Putty, you can have the putty connection run a command on the remote side
http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.53b/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#3.7.3   using the -m flag.

Comment: HI, i actually use some shell scripts i created on the server, but only for running multiple commands in a row.

Comment: I just looked into the -m flag but that seems to only be able to run the commands in the file passed as argument, at startup, right? This isn't a bad thing, could be useful to create a simple separate UI program having buttons or a clickable list that triggers each command... I would have to write it, and create one file per command... but it would get me what i want...eventually :)  It probably can't do 'su' and enter the pass for me, but i could add my user to sudo-ers and use sudo .

Comment: Yeah. you can have a couple putty commands that include the needed script/command to run. instead of needing a password you can you public/private key set in putty so you don't need a password. then you can use sudo with a password or add `user ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL)` in `/etc/sudoers` and you won't need a passowrd to sudo.

Comment: Thou there are no windows ones that I know of. there are lots of linux ones that are very nice if you ever have another machine to manage from

Answer (score 0):

Use aliases in your .bashrc file like so:

In ~/.bashrc add

alias [name your alias]=[enter your command]

Save it and exit, then type "source .bashrc" in your terminal and press Enter.

Then you can use your alias.

Here is an example:

alias all='ls -als'

If your command or commands associated with your alias have spaces use quotes.

Cygwin works well if you are looking for something different to use for ssh.